# Initialization differences between character and Integer pointers

Tags: c

This has no runtime error

```
int main()
{
    char *p = "Hello"; 
}
```

This gives runtime error

```
int main()
{
   int *p; 
   *p = 5; 
}
```

I cant understand the reason why this is happening. Would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: I stared at this for a minute and couldn't see the problem. Not worth a question downvote in my opinion. Update: glad to see it's removed.

Comment: In addition to the provided answers, you should (in this case) declare `p` in the first snippet as `const char*` instead of `char*`. This will make the compiler catch any assignments to `*p`, which would result in undefined behavior, which is invoked by writing to string literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example points pointer `p` to a literal string, so `p` is pointing to valid memory.

Your section declares the pointer `p` but does not point to to any memory address.  Then the next statement `*p = 5` dereferences `p`, which tries to store `5` at the memory address stored in pointer `p`.  Since you have not pointed `p` to valid memory, your application crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Your second snippet is *undefined behaviour* as the pointer is uninitialised.

Your first snippet could get you into trouble too: you ought to write `const char *p = "Hello";`. This is because the string text will be added to a table of string literals by the C runtime library. It's *undefined behaviour* to modify it. Using `const` helps enforce that.

Answer (score 1):

The first program sets the value of the pointer, and is well-defined (so long as you don't attempt to modify the string).

The second program assigns a value through an uninitialized pointer (and therefore has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

The following is a *rough* equivalent of the first program, but using `int`:

```
int main()
{
   int val = 5;
   int *p = &val;
}
```